# Expand/Condense all UICollectionView Cells in a UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am trying to code the button in the top right so that when tapped, it'll only display the name in the white bar and **not** display the photo, or the position of the person on the card. Here is a photo illustrating the expanded section.
[image: Expanded card section]

I tried manipulating the size by using the `sizeForItemAt` in `collectionView`, but that did not work. Here is what I did:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize{
        let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? CardCollectionViewCell
        if expand {
            cell?.profileimage.alpha = 0
            cell?.poscomp.alpha = 0
            return CGSize(width: 360, height: 208)
        } else {
            cell?.profileimage.alpha = 1
            cell?.poscomp.alpha = 1
            return CGSize(width: 360, height: 40)
        }
    }
```

And for the button, I did...

```
@IBAction func collapse(_ sender: Any) {

        expand = !expand
        for index in 0...associates.count {
            cardCollectionView.reloadItems(at: [IndexPath(row: 0, section: index)])
        }
}
```

Is there a correct/simpler way to manipulate heights and elements in a CollectionViewCell?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing right code, but I din't recognise your issue.
Add following code which are working fine, that may be expecting you.

```
var expandedHeight              : CGFloat = 200
var notExpandedHeight           : CGFloat = 50
var isExpanded                  = false
```

In button's action method add code to reload `collectionView` with/without animation

```
@IBAction func btnExpandTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    self.isExpanded = !self.isExpanded

    // Simple reload
    // self.cvList.reloadData()

    // Reload with animation
    for i in 0..<5 {

        let indexPath = IndexPath(item: i, section: 0)

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.8, delay: 0.0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.9, initialSpringVelocity: 0.9, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: {
            self.cvList.reloadItems(at: [indexPath])
        }, completion: { success in
            print("success")
        })
    }
}
```

Add `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout`'s `sizeForItemAt` method and add following code to change height of collection view cell.

```
extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

        if isExpanded {
            return CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.width, height: 200)
        } else {
            return CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.width, height: 40)
        }
    }
}
```

Check following link for demo App.

https://freeupload.co/files/02c31165b3c6876678301ae075f5722b.zip